# Does "double" conditional zero expectation follow from two conditional zero expectations?

Tags: conditional-expectation

If we have $E(x|y)=E(x|z)=0$, does it follow that $E(x|y,z)=0$?

Comment: Your second conditional expectation specified no value. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $E[z|y] = -y$, $E[y|z]= -z$ and $x = y +z$. Then $E[x|y] = y  + E[z|y] = y -y = 0$, $E[x|z] = E[y|z] + z = -z  + z = 0$ but $E[x|y,z] = y + z$.